# In Python, why did I get -9223372036854775808 when I set one row of a 2D array as np.nan?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, nan

In Python, if I define a 2D array, and set the second row as np.nan, the second row will become all -9223372036854775808 rather than missing values. An example is here:

```
b = np.array(
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
 [0, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 5],
 [0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
 [0, 0, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
 [0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]])

b[1, :] = np.nan
print(b)

[[                   0                    0                    0
                 0                    0                    0
                 0                    0                    0
                 5]
[-9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808
 -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808
 -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808
 -9223372036854775808]
[                   0                    0                    0
                 3                    6                    6
                 6                    6                    6
                 6]
[                   0                    0                    3
                 4                    6                    6
                 6                    6                    6
                 6]
[                   0                    1                    2
                 4                    4                    4
                 4                    4                    4
                 4]]
```

Does anyone have any idea? And how should I correctly assign one row to np.nan?

For your reference, I am running these codes on python 3.7.10 environment created by mamba on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-132-generic x86_64).

Comment: Running your code in my Mac Python 3.9.4 (NumPy 1.21.0) environment, I get "ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer" for `b[1, :] = np.nan`...

Comment: Related, though, is that `-9223372036854775808` is the minimal value a 64-bit signed integer can hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.nan` is a special floating point value that cannot be used in integer arrays. Since `b` is an array of integers, the code `b[1, :] = np.nan` attempts to convert `np.nan` to an integer, which is an undefined behavior. See [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13101) for a discussion of a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

First of all **nan** is a special value for float arrays only.

I tried running your code on my python 3.8(64 bit environment) on Windows x-64 based.

```
b = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
              [0, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 5],
              [0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
              [0, 0, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
              [0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]])
b[1, :] = np.nan
print(b)
```

This is what I got

```
[[          0           0           0           0           0           0
        0           0           0           5]
 [-2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648
  -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648]
 [          0           0           0           3           6           6
        6           6           6           6]
 [          0           0           3           4           6           6
        6           6           6           6]
 [          0           1           2           4           4           4
        4           4           4           4]]
```

In case of **int** array I got lower bound of **int** in place of **NaN** and you are also getting the same depending on your environment.

So instead of **int** array you can use **float** array.

```
b = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
              [0, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 5],
              [0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
              [0, 0, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
              [0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]], dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 2):

You initialised your array with integers. Integers do not have a possible "nan" value and will resort to the minimal value. A quick fix is to initialize your array as np.floats, they are allowed to be "nan":

```
b = np.array(
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
 [0, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 5],
 [0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
 [0, 0, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
 [0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]], dtype=np.float)

b[1, :] = np.nan
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

This number is equal to -2⁶³, which is the minimum value for the 64 bit integer limit. I don't code in python, but what it seems to me is that your code didn't recognize NaN as a value so it went to the lowest possible value it could recognize.